# Giving $\nabla^{2} f(\mathbf{x}) \succeq mI$,how to calculate $\|(\nabla^{2} f(\mathbf{x}))^{-1}\| $

Tags: hessian-matrix

In the 《Introduction to Nonlinear Optimization Theory, Algorithms, and Applications with MATLAB》page 85, "Combining the latter equality with the fact that $\nabla^{2} f(\mathbf{x}) \succeq  mI$ implies that $\|(\nabla^{2} f(\mathbf{x}))^{-1}\| \leq \frac{1}{m}$",how to deduce.$I$ is identity matrix and $\succeq$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: $\nabla^2f(x) \succeq  mI\implies \lambda_{\min}\geq m$. Then if $\nabla^2f(x)$ is invertible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hessian $\nabla^2 f(x)$ is symmetric and positive definite, hence there exists an orthogal matrix $Q$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that
$$
\nabla^2 f(x)=QDQ^T
$$
We can then proceed the check that $\nabla^2 f(x)-mI=QDQ^T-mQQ^T=Q(D-mI)Q^T \geq 0$ implies
$$
D-mI \geq 0
$$
Hence no entry of the diagonal matrix $D$ is smaller than $m$. However, the inverse of $D=diag(d_1,...,d_n)$ is just given by $D^{-1}=diag(d_1^{-1},...,d_n^{-1})$ (note that no entry is bigger than $\frac{1}{m}$) and the inverse of $\nabla^2 f(x)$ is given by
$$
(\nabla^2 f(x))^{-1}=QD^{-1}Q^T
$$
We can now proceed to compute its norm:
$$
||(\nabla^2 f(x))^{-1}||_2=\sup_{||y||_2=1}||(\nabla^2 f(x))^{-1}y||_2= \\
\sup_{||y||_2=1}||QD^{-1}Q^Ty||_2=\sup_{||y||_2=1}||D^{-1}y||_2 \leq \frac{1}{m}
$$
There are different proofs using the properties of the matrix norms, but I went with a more elementary approach.

Comment: How to get the last equality and inequality

Comment: Orthogonal matrices preserve the inner product. And the last one is just the definition of the matrix 2 norm. What is the largest eigenvalue of the diagonal matrix $D^{-1}$?

Comment: $\|QD^{-1}Q^Ty\|_2=\sqrt{y^TQD^{-1}Q^TQD^{-1}Q^Ty}=\sqrt{y^TQD^{-1}D^{-1}Q^Ty}=\|D^{-1}Q^Ty\|_2$,it seems not right

Comment: $$ (D^{-1}Q^T)^T=QD^{-1}$$ and apply the same trick...

Comment: You can also take the sup over all $||Q^Ty||_2=1$, which is the same set as $||y||_2=1$.

Comment: Thanks,now I understand.I have the last question,this prove seems only for 2-norm

Comment: Yes, it does only work for the 2 norm.